# How to make sure the database server is always available while using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework in VS2015 and I wanted to make sure that every time I get/delete data from the entities the database server is always in a good connection state.

I know some of the ways to handle the exception, but is there a better way where I do not have to add try catch to every function? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of adding try-catch in every function, you can configure a global exception handler to handle database connection failure and doing retry, etc.

Comment: pay a lot of money for sla's with 100% availability - but this is probably not what you are asking for :)
You should not need to add a try-catch for every function. Search for global/unhandled exception handlers

Comment: a good way .   Thanks and I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one of our projects we have used [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) to handle the transient errors while connecting to database, and loved it.

> Polly is a .NET library that allows developers to express transient
>   exception- and fault-handling policies such as Retry, Retry Forever,
>   Wait and Retry or Circuit Breaker in a fluent and thread-safe manner.

We have configured the Polly to handle the exception for connection failure and retried it in our case

```
    // Retry multiple times, calling an action on each retry  
    // with the current exception and retry count Policy
        .Handle<ExceptionIWAntToHandle>()
        .Retry(3, (exception, retryCount) =>
        {
            // do something 
        });
```

And yes as suggested in comments, have a centralized location for this.